# sql query Insert Into with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add some values in a table with a Select procedure for 1 value like this.

```
INSERT INTO product(productname, productprice, productcategorynumber) 
VALUES ('12', '12', (SELECT productcategorynumber 
                     FROM product_category 
                     WHERE productcategoryname = 'DRINKS'));
```

I Receive the following error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint

thanx for help

Comment: Which fields have a unique constraint?

Comment: Your syntax should work fine.  The error is about the values you're trying to insert.  Perhaps the productname is unqiue, and there already is a row with `productname = '12'`

Comment: Are you using oracle  ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for `values`:

```
INSERT INTO product(productname, productprice, productcategorynumber) 
SELECT '12', '12', productcategorynumber 
FROM product_category 
WHERE productcategoryname = 'DRINKS';
```

I'm presuming these are not the actually values you want, but it'll hopefully put you on the right track. (Is there a unique constraint on productname? If so, you need to adjust the query accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a constraint on one of the fields :(productname, productprice, productcategorynumber).
Check your table to see which field has a unique constraint on it and then you need insert distinct value for that field.

Here is a statement which will list the constraints for you in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT  constraint_name, constraint_type FROM information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'product'
```

you should also be able use the below command to see the constraints for this product table

```
\d product
```